# streaming a video using phonegap app for android

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, video, streaming

I have created an app using phonegap,jquerymobile and html5.
it contains video streaming. the content of the page comes dynamically which contains iframe. I tried it on android 4.1 and it was working fine. I wasn't able to play it in android 2.2.1/2.3.3/2.3.6 versions.

I wanted to view video using iframe in android device 2.3 version and above.
the iframe code is shown below:

```
<iframe src="http://fast.wistia.com/embed/playlists/mqr7n354p2?autoAdvance=false&media_0_0%5BautoPlay%5D=false&media_0_0%5BcontrolsVisibleOnLoad%5D=false&version=v1&videoOptions%5BautoPlay%5D=false&videoOptions%5BvideoHeight%5D=180&videoOptions%5BvideoWidth%5D=320&videoOptions%5BvolumeControl%5D=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_playlist" name="wistia_playlist" width="320" height="180"></iframe>
```

below is the link where you can find a sample code.
http://jsfiddle.net/maneeshn/vtP8e/1/

Comment: Have you successfully achieved your task ? can u please let me know any tutorial or Library so that i can follow for video live streaming

Comment: i am getting error 01-06 20:35:02.745: E/Web Console(21835): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'medias' of undefined:7
when i applied your code in my streamingFile.html just for testing purpose